# java.sql.SQLException: lock wait time out exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hi in my project i am  have created 2 tables which was Role_header and Role_details tables.
And also Role_details table is referring to the Role_header table.

In my java class i have two method they are

1. `insertRoleHeader(...)` --> which will be called first and set conn.setAutoCommit(false).i       didn't commit this because following this i want to insert role_details with multiple records in Role_details table. so i will call this method first, if any exceptions thrown. i have set this to rollback in catch.
2. `insertRoleDetails(.....)` --> this method will be called by forloop. each and every calling of this method i will commit. at that time i am getting error as `java.sql.SQLException: lock wait time out exceeded; try restarting transaction`.

my sample code is here:

```
public void insertHeader(RoleMasterSupport rMS) throws SQLException {
    connectDB();
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        roleMasterConn.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = roleMasterConn.createStatement();
        String sql = "insert into role_header( create_user, " +
                     "create_date, " +
                     "run_user, " +
                     "run_date, " +
                     "role_id, " +
                     "role_name, "+
                     "remarks) " +
                     "values('"+Constants.sUserName+"', now(), "
                    + "'"+Constants.sUserName+"', now(), "
                    + "'"+rMS.getsRoleID()+"', '"+rMS.getsRoleName()+"', "
                    + "'"+rMS.getsRemarks()+"') ";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.close();                   
    } catch (SQLException e) {  
        roleMasterConn.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}


public void insertDetails(RoleMasterSupport rMS, TableModel model) throws SQLException
{
    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        dbop.insertDetail(rMS, rMS.getaLScreenNames().get(i), 
                rMS.getaLAdd().get(i), rMS.getaLView().get(i), 
                rMS.getaLModify().get(i), rMS.getaLDelete().get(i));
    }
}

public void insertDetail(RoleMasterSupport rMS, String sScreenName, String sAdd, String sView, String sModify, String sDelete) throws SQLException
{
    connectDB();
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {
        roleMasterConn.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = roleMasterConn.createStatement();
        String sql = "insert into role_details( create_user, " +
                     "create_date, " +
                     "run_user, " +
                     "run_date, " +
                     "role_id, " +
                     "screen_name, " +
                     "modify_screen, " +
                     "add_screen, " +       
                     "delete_screen, " +       
                     "view_screen) " +
                     "values('"+Constants.sUserName+"', now(), "
                     + "'"+Constants.sUserName+"', now(), "
                     + "'"+rMS.getsRoleID()+"', '"+sScreenName+"', "
                     + "'"+sModify+"', '"+sAdd+"', "
                     + "'"+sDelete+"', '"+sView+"') ";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        roleMasterConn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        roleMasterConn.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify the problem. what is wrong with this and what do you what to happen etc.

Comment: i am getting this error java.sql.SQLException: lock wait time out exceeded; try restarting transaction. plz giude me to resolve it.

Comment: `connectDB` is shown twice in the source code which suggests two connections are used instead of one. If two connections are used, one connection might never commit and that could cause the error.